# Trouble understanding function comparing password hashes

Tags: security, hash, hmac

This method is from Udacity's Web Dev Unit 4.

```
  def check_secure_val(secure_val): 
        val = secure_val.split('|')[0] 
        if secure_val == make_secure_val(val): 
            return val
```

If you intake secure val and get val from the first part of the secure val, and then compare secure val to the hash of the val (which itself came from secure val), wouldn't the equality always be true?

Btw, make secure val is

```
    def make_secure_val(val):
        return '%s|%s' % (val, hmac.new(secret, val).hexdigest())
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. `secure_val` doesn't necessarily have the right cookie, just a cookie with the right hash.